# Was there ever a mortal restored to life after having succumbed to death?

Tags: scripture, vedas, atma, death, life

I heard that the son of Brihaspati was restored to life. Was there ever an ordinary human being restored to life after death?

Comment: Read ramayana all vanarasa brought back by rama using sanjeevani brought by hanuman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son of King Harishchandra chandra was restored to life.

> The birds spoke:
> Then Indra, the lord, going to the funeral pile, poured down from the sky a shower of nectar that prevents sudden death, and a very copious shower of flowers, accompanied with the sound of the heavenly drums, here and there on that closelygathered assemblage of gods. **Then the high-souled king’s son arose, very youthful in body, in perfeet health, placid in his organs and mind.** And king Hariścandra immediately embraced his son; and in possessing his wife regained his own Fortune. He was decked with heavenly garlands; and was happy, completely satisfied in heart, and filled with supreme joy.

> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-markandeya-purana/d/doc117035.html

A Brahmin lady revived her husband through Shaligrama stone.

> 55. A certain Brāhmaṇa lady became widow on the fifth day after her marriage. By making the gift of a Śālagrāma stone in the month of Kārttika she revived her husband.

> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371643.html#note-e-139390

Savitri's husband Satyavan was also revived from death.

> I ask for this boon,
> 'May Satyavan be restored to life, for by that your words will be made true.'"
> "Markandeya continued,
> 'Thereupon saying,—So be it,—Vivasvat’s son, Yama, the dispenser of justice, untied his noose, and with cheerful heart said these words to Savitri,

> Then **Satyavan regained his consciousness**, and affectionately eyeing Savitri again and again, like one come home after a sojourn in a strange land, he addressed her thus,

> **Vana Parva CCLXLV**

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes.

There's one story found in the Padma Mahā-Purāṇa.

The son (known by Vedaśarman) of a ceratin [Śivaśarman](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241963.html), a pious Brāhmiṇa, was restored back to life.

---

**The basic story goes like** - the Brāhmiṇa Śivaśarman tests his sons one by one. Vedaśarman is assigned with the task to request a young women to become the wife of his old father. But, the woman did not want to become the wife of the old Śivaśarman. She puts a condition -  *"If you want me as wife for your father, please cut off your head with your own hands for my pleasure."* Vedaśarman drew his sword and very happily cut off his head and presented it to the woman. Then, later on, Śivaśarman's another son (named Dharmaśarman) is able to revive his dead brother from Dharmarāj Yamarāja's boon.

---

> #### [Chapter 2](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364209.html) - Life is Restored to Vedaśarman
>
> Section 2 -
> Bhūmi-khaṇḍa (section on the earth)
>
> > 10. to 11. Then Dharma said: “This will take place by my favour.” When these very significant words were uttered, the very wise
> >     Vedaśarman got up, as if he had slept; he said to Dharmaśarman: “O brother, where has that respectable woman gone? Where would be
> >     the father?”
>
> > 12. He told in brief how the father had appointed him. Knowing that, Dharmaśarman, who was delighted, said to him:
>
> > 13. **“O glorious one, O brother, be favourable to me today only with (my having restored your) head and life. Who else is there like you to
> >     me on the earth?”**
>
> ...
>
> > 15. to 17a. Both, delighted in their minds went to their father there (i.e. to the place where he was). Both stood close together. **Then Dharmaśarman spoke to his father, the excellent and lustrous Śivaśarman: “O glorious one, due to my penance and life Vedaśarman has been brought (back).**

Comment: If I recall correctly , is he the same sivasharman who saw all the lokas with vishnudutas and then got vaikuntha ??

Comment: @ShriRambhakt are you talking about the story from the Skanda Purana?

Comment: Yes I'm talking about that :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that, details vary, but that could very well be the classic "kalpa-bheda". @ShriRambhakt

Comment: Same perspective :)